# resolvconf-pull-resolved.service is a disabled or a static unit

Tags: 18.04, wireless, resolvconf

I am having a problem with the WIFI connection. The installed os is Ubuntu 18.04 and I got the following error on the browser.

Error on Browser: activation of network connection failed

Based on the investigation that I did, I run the following two lines of code on the terminal.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install resolvconf
```

And then, I run the following command but got another error and I do not know how to fix it. I would appreciate if you may support me to solve this issue.

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf
```

Second Error: resolvconf-pull-resolved.service is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.

Thanks in advance!